Using equivalence of quantifiers to show $\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)$
Background
Quantifier distribution and negation laws
$\forall x(P(x)\wedge Q(x))=\forall xP(x)\wedge \forall xQ(x)$
$\exists y(P(y)\vee Q(y))=\exists yP(y) \vee \exists yQ(y)$
$\sim (\forall x P(x))=\exists x \sim P(x)$
$\sim (\exists x P(x))=\forall x \sim P(x)$
Theorem and notations on algebraic sets
The notations and definitions are as follow:
Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field.  Fix a positing integer $n$ and denote by $A$ the polynomial ring $A=k[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}].$  Typically ideals of $A$ will be denoted by $a,b,\ldots.$  We call the set $\mathbb{A}^{n}=\{(x_{1},\ldots x_{n})\in k^{n}\}$ an affine $n$-space.  Members of points in affine $n$-space, and the function $P\mapsto x_{j}(P)$ gives the coordinates of the points.
To each subset $S$ of polynomials in $A$, associate the locus of common zeros, or zero locus of the members of $S:$
$V(S)=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^{n}| f(P)=0 \text{ for all } f\in S\}$
$V(S)$ is called an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$.  If $S$ is a finite set $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\}$ of polynomials, then $V(\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\})$ is abbreviated as $V(f_{1},\dots,f_{n}).$ From the definition that $V(S)=\bigcap_{f\in S} V(f)$ for any subset $S$ of $A$.
Theorem:  Affine algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ have the following properties:
$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$ if the $S_{\alpha}$'s are arbitrary subsets of $A$.
Proof:
$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})\quad\quad\quad (*)$.
Question
In Theorem above, $S\subset A$, if we let $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}\subset A$, where the $S_{\alpha}$'s is an index family subsets of $A$ with an index $I$, then the statement of the theorem is: $V(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}V(S_{\alpha})$ and the proof would be written with the proper index set notation as:
$$V(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}V(S_{\alpha})\quad\quad (**)$$.
For the middle two equalities $\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)$ in $(**)$, when I tried to show that the two are equivalent using rules of inference from symbolic logic, distributiotion and negation laws for quantifiers, I am not having any success.  The left hand side of $(**)$ is $\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\forall f(f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}}S_{\alpha}\Rightarrow P\in V(f))=\forall f(\exists\alpha(\alpha\in I \wedge f\in S_{\alpha}) \Rightarrow P\in V(f))=\forall f(\sim\exists\alpha(\alpha\in I \wedge f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee P\in V(f))$.  The right hand side of $(**)$ is:  $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)=\forall\alpha(\alpha\in I\Rightarrow P\in \bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f))=\forall\alpha(\alpha\in I\Rightarrow (\forall f(f\in S_{\alpha} \Rightarrow  P\in V(f))))=\forall\alpha(\sim(\alpha\in I)\vee (\forall f(\sim(f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee  P\in V(f))))$.  I am not able to show:
$$\forall f(\sim\exists\alpha(\alpha\in I \wedge f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee P\in V(f))=\forall\alpha(\sim(\alpha\in I)\vee (\forall f(\sim(f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee  P\in V(f)))).$$
It seems like the existential quantifier on the left hand side simply disappears on the right hand side after applying quantifier distributions law.

Can't you do something like this:
$$ P \in \bigcap_{f\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in I} S_\alpha} V(f)
\Leftrightarrow \forall f\in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} S_\alpha : P\in V(f)
\Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha\in I \ \forall f\in S_\alpha : P\in V(f)
\Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha\in I : P\in \bigcap_{f\in S_\alpha} V(f)
\Leftrightarrow P\in \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} \bigcap_{f\in S_\alpha} V(f). $$

@SeverinSchraven sorry I made a typo in my previous comment, so I am reposting.  What I don't understand is that in:$f\in \cup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha$, how does one get $\exists {\alpha\in I}\wedge f\in S_\alpha=\forall \alpha\in I \ \forall f\in S_\alpha$? I mean how does one make $\exists\alpha\in I$ to $\forall \alpha \in I$?

There are more direct ways to prove that
$$\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)$$
but let us answer your more specific question: how to prove the equivalence between
$$\forall f(\sim\exists\alpha(\alpha\in I \wedge f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee P\in V(f))\tag1\label{eq1}$$
and
$$\forall\alpha(\sim(\alpha\in I)\vee (\forall f(\sim(f\in S_{\alpha}) \vee  P\in V(f)))).\tag2\label{eq2}$$
Introducing the abreviations $A(\alpha):=\alpha\notin I$, $B(f,\alpha):=f\notin S_\alpha$, $C(f):=P\in V(f)$, these two propositions can be rewritten respectively
$$\forall f\left(\left\{\forall\alpha[A(\alpha)\lor B(f,\alpha)]\right\}\lor C(f)\right)\tag{1'}\label{eq1'}$$
and
$$\forall\alpha\left(A(\alpha)\lor\left\{\forall f[B(f,\alpha)\lor C(f)]\right\}\right).\tag{2'}\label{eq2'}$$
\eqref{eq1'} is equivalent to
$$\forall f\left(\forall\alpha[A(\alpha)\lor B(f,\alpha)\lor C(f)]\right)\tag{1''}\label{eq1''}$$
because $\alpha$ is not a free variable in $C(f)$, and similarly, \eqref{eq2'} is equivalent to
$$\forall\alpha\left(\forall f[A(\alpha)\lor B(f,\alpha)\lor C(f)]\right)\tag{2''}\label{eq2''}$$
because $f$ is not a free variable in $A(\alpha)$.
Edit. My 'direct' way to prove that the two sets $\bigcap_{f\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha}V(f)$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_\alpha}V(f)$ are equal is to check (choosing the same letter $P$ as you) that $P$ belongs to the former iff it belongs to the latter:
$$\begin{align}P\in\bigcap_{f\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha}V(f)&\iff\forall f\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha\quad P\in V(f)\\
&\iff\forall f\left((\exists\alpha\in I\quad f\in S_\alpha)\implies P\in V(f)\right)\\&\iff(\forall f)(\forall\alpha)\left((\alpha\in I\land f\in S_\alpha)\implies P\in V(f)\right)\\&\iff(\forall\alpha\in I)(\forall f\in S_\alpha)\quad P\in V(f)\\&\iff P\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_\alpha}V(f)
\end{align}$$
I used freely the abreviations $(\forall u\in U)(\dots)$ for $(\forall u)(u\in U\implies\dots)$, and $(\exists u\in U)(\dots)$ for $(\exists u)(u\in U\land\dots)$. I also used that if $\alpha$ is not a free variable in $B$ then $(\exists\alpha\quad A(\alpha))\implies B$ is equivalent to $(\forall\alpha)(A(\alpha)\implies B)$.

Thank you for clearing it up.  I tried to show that idenity, and I noticed depending which book I am using, the notations for index family of sets in set builder notation either is displayed as $\cup F={x:\exists A(A\in F\wedge x\in A) }:=\exists A\in F(x\in A)$ or $x\in\cup F \leftrightarrow{x:(\exists A\in F)(x\in A) }$, similarily, $\cap F={x:\forall A(A\in F\to x\in A) }:=\forall A\in F(x\in A)$ or $x\in\cap F \leftrightarrow{x:(\forall A\in F)(x\in A) }$.  I  concluded if i had any chance of doing the question, I had to use the second notation.  With the first one,...

...the way the round bracket is placed make me think that the scope of the quantifier extends past the connective (disjunction, and conjunction). I think you are referring to the following prenex normal forms:
$\forall x(\varphi\vee \psi)\equiv (\forall x\varphi\vee\psi)$
$\forall x(\varphi\vee \psi)\equiv (\varphi\vee\forall x\psi)$
$\exists x(\varphi\cdot \psi)\equiv (\exists x \varphi\cdot\psi)$
$\exists x(\varphi\cdot \psi)\equiv (\varphi\cdot\exists x\psi)$
$(\exists x\varphi\supset\psi)\equiv \forall x(\varphi\supset \psi)$...

...$(\forall x\varphi\supset\psi)\equiv\exists x(\varphi\supset \psi)$
$(\varphi\supset\forall x\psi)\equiv \forall x(\varphi\supset \psi)$
$(\varphi\supset\exists x\psi)\equiv \exists x(\varphi\supset \psi)$
I actually had to loook them up.  I dtook a course in symbolic logic, and for some reasons, I did not learn about them.  I looked through the textbook that was for that course and nowhere were the above eight identifies mentioned.

I did not  yet read carefully your comments, but first of all, you should'nt write an $=$ sign between a set and a statement (like you already did in your post). For instance, the set ${x:\exists A(A\in F\wedge x\in A) }$ is not the same type of object as the statement $\exists A\in F(x\in A)$ (which is equivalent to $\exists A(A\in F\wedge x\in A)$). Similarly, the statement $x\in\cup F$ (which is equivalent to $(\exists A\in F)(x\in A)$) is not the set ${x:(\exists A\in F)(x\in A) }$.

if it is not too much trouble, can I ask you to look at this post.  I just want to know how to define the compatible function $f$ given a direct limit of subgroups.  I am having a lot of trouble since there is a lot of notations and I am not sure how to match which set to what set in the definition.

Sure I shall have a look, but let me first read and answer your previous (chain of) 3 comments. I think I already answered the first one: all these notations, once corrected as I indicated, are equivalent. I don't believe in any of the equivalences of your 2nd comment.

I am following Velleman's text.  I read the book in high school and had the symbolic logic course awhile afterwards.  I never took one of those learn how to do math proof course.  Everytime I ask something here abstract algebra related, I get told how bad I need to brush up on my mathematical logic.

I don't know if you are aware that the statement:  $\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)$, textbook in commutative algebra/algebraic geometry, the statement of its proof is "obvious from definition".  When I ask about that little little equality here, everyone tells me it is obvious and I am making a mountain out of a molehill.

Follow up of my previous (updated, please look) comment: I don't believe either in any of the equivalences of your 3rd comment. As for the 'obvious' equality in the title of your post, since you don't seem to understand @FShrike's answer, I shall rewrite it inside my answer.

I did not understand what FShrike was referring to when he mentioned infima and adjointness of "for all"  Also, the various text in how union and intersection for index family of sets in terms of set builder notation, and how that is related to scope of quanitfier and distribution law, what you mentioned, I did not know about it.  If I learned it in the past as some sort of derivation exercsie in symbolic logic text, I must have either forgottten about it or did not find it important enough to remember it.

there is one other thing I want to ask about intepreting the meaning of $\cap_{f\in \cup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha}$. As an example, suppose $\alpha={1,2,\cdot,10},$ and $f$ is in some of the $S_\alpha$, say $S_1,S_3,S_5,S_7,S_{10}$.  $\cap_{f\in \cup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha}$ would mean that we only care about those $f$s in those five $S_\alpha$, and $f\not\in {S_2,S_2,S_4,S_6,S_8,S_9}$, is not captured in the notation:  $\cap_{f\in \cup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha}$.  Is the correct way of understanding it?"

Let $S:=\cup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha$. First of all, $\cap_{f\in S}$ means nothing on its own, like $\sum_{n=0}^5$. It has to be followed by some set indexed by $f$ (respectively, some number indexed by $n$). Secondly, after having determined $S$, you can forget about the $S_i$'s. Last but not least: in $\cap_{f\in S}V(f)$, there is no specific $f$ involved. $f$ is a dummy variable. $\cap_{f\in S}V(f)=\cap_{g\in S}V(g).$

When you saY once I have determined $S$, I can forget about the $S_i$s, Do you mean that after I determined how many of the $S_i$ have $f$ as eleemnt?

Nono, I really mean determined just the set $S$. And again: there is no $f$ involved. For instance if $I={1,2}$ and $S_i={f_0,f_i}$ and $V_i:=V(f_i)$ then $S={f_0,f_1,f_2}$ and $\cap_{f\in S}V(f)=V_0\cap V_1\cap V_2$.

oh okay okay.  All this time, when I see $f\in \cup S_\alpha$, i keep wondering about the possibility that for some of the $S_\alpha$, $f\not\in S_\alpha$.

Of course it is possible, and we don't care. For instance in my example (where I assumed implicitely that $f_0,f_1,f_2$ are distinct), $f_1\notin S_2$ but $f_1\in S$.

Thank you so much for clarifying this for me.  <3<3<3

Show double containment and the fact that intersections are infima, or equivalently use adjointness of "for all". I don't know enough logic to be able to say if you can purely formally derive this without extra knowledge about what the rules of your system are; I guess the proof I'm about to outline is a proof in the logic of some complete Heyting algebra.
In one direction we must check that if $f\in\bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$ then: $V(f)\supseteq\bigcap_{\alpha'}\bigcap_{f'}V(f')$. Well, existential instantiation gives me $\alpha$ with $f\in S_\alpha$ and then $V(f)\supseteq\bigcap_{f'\in S_\alpha}V(f')$ by considering $f'=f$ for this specific $\alpha$, so $V(f)\supseteq\bigcap_{\alpha'}\bigcap_{f'}V(f')$ as well. The other direction is extremely similar. It must be shown that for all $\alpha'$, $\bigcap_{f'\in S_\alpha}V(f')\supseteq\bigcap_fV(f)$ and to that end it must be shown that for all $f'\in S_\alpha$, $V(f')\supseteq\bigcap_fV(f)$ and this is immediate by instantiating at $f=f'$.

@Seth Could you check what I wrote and more specifically say which part you're not confident in? I'm using the infimum property as the main point; $\bigcap_{j\in J}S_j\supseteq W$ iff. $S_j\supseteq W$ for all $j$

actually, what does it mean for intersections to be infima and adjointness of "for all" mean?

after looking up the infima property, I stilll don't understand how the existential quantifier disappears?

how did you make the existential quantifier disappear. The thing is, in the statement of the theorem, does it in an apriori sense sssume that each of the $$'s is in at least one of the $\alpha$? So we don't get say the fo;llowing situation: if $$ only contain the family of subsets say: ${1,2,\ldots,{10}}$ and one of the $$ doesn't contain any $$. Because if you write out $\in \cup\alpha \alpha$, then in english, that means $$ is in at least one of the $\alpha$ but not necessarily in all of the $S_\alpha$ (I repost my previous comment due to some typos)

Also how does one make $\exists\alpha\in I$ to $\forall \alpha \in I$?
